# How to scrape for text by id

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping

I want to repeatedly scrape a website every second and print what it finds- but when it scrapes the website all it prints '[]'. I have tried it using id and class but neither seem to be working. Also the text that i am trying to scrape changes every couple of seconds, would that be a problem? Any advice would be useful thanks.

```
page = driver.get("https://www.memrise.com/course/2021573/french-1-145/garden/speed_review/?source_element=ms_mode&source_screen=eos_ms")
page = requests.get("https://www.memrise.com/course/2021573/french-1-145/garden/speed_review/?source_element=ms_mode&source_screen=eos_ms")
element = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Log in with Google')
element.click()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
while True:
    front_half = soup.find_all(id='prompt-row')
    print(front_half)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to repeat it, put it in a `for` or `while` loop and at the start of either, put a `time.sleep()` with however long you want to wait in seconds.

As for the `[]` that means that it hasn't found anything with the classes `qquestion qtext`. To me it looks like that page doesn't have anything with those classes. Also, it should be `page.text` and not `page.contents`

Comment: Thanks, but by inspecting the page I can see that the sentence I want to print from the page has a class of ‘qquestion qtext’ so I don’t know why it is not working. I also tried putting a ‘time.sleep()’ before it because it takes you straight to a log in page where you log in before going to the page with the text I want to scrape on, but that didn’t seem to work either.

Comment: @Jack, The elements you see while inspecting the web page are only what you see in browser. The real content, which your request renders is in page source. So, use the page source to decide the classes and all.